# navbar overflows (x) page content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a website using `Bootstrap 3`. When in responsive mode, my `index.html` page has a horizontal scroll bar. I could not find what is causing this overflow-x. This only happens in my `index.html` page.

In the other pages, this overflow is not present. At first I thought it was something in the Contact section of my `index.html` which has a box shadow which caused the overflow in x. Even  after removing it, the overflow was present which made me conclude that the navbar is the one causing the issue.

I am not able to find what is causing this issue.

**Screenshot:** (the overflow on the right side)

[image]

**HTML code for navbar:**

```
<header id="main">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
                    <!-- <img class="img img-responsive" src="www/images/srs-logo.jpg" alt="SRS Constructions"> -->
                    SRS Constructions
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a class="main" href="#main">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown" id="nav-about">
                        <a href="#about" class="dropdown-toggle main" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="left:0;right: auto">
                            <li><a href="about.html">The Founder</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="health-policy.html">HSE Policy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="quality-policy.html">Quality Policy</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="main" href="#services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a class="main" href="#projects">Our Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a class="main" href="#whyus">Why Us</a></li>
                    <li><a class="main" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I have not added any specific css which alters the width of the navbar.

**CSS for navbar:**

```
/*Navbar styles*/

.navbar {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    font-size: 15px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
    min-height: 80px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 80px;
}


.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
    background-color: #b4a28f;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .navbar-brand > img {
        width: 40%;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: 90px;
        margin-top: -80px;
    }
    #footer {
        color: #2e2e2e;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
    #footer {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
}

.navbar-brand > img {
    width: 30%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

**The site is also available [here](http://srsconstructions.herokuapp.com)**

Please help me with fixing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you follow the "rules" for the grid...

Columns `.col-*` must be wrapped in `.row`, and *only* `.col-*` should be the immediate child of a  `.row`

`.row` > `.gallery` in the projects section is causing the scrollbar since `.gallery` is not a column.

Comment: omg yes. That was the one causing the issue. Once I put it inside a container, the issue is fixed. Can you please tell me how you were able to find the issue ? It might be helpful for me to identify issues like this in the future.

Comment: Hit F12 in the browser to inspect the html. You can right click also right click on an element, select inspect, and then "remove node" until you find what's causing the problem.

Comment: I tried to inspect and glazed through the nodes to find which had the content. Anyway thanks for the tip.